# Unity keeps removing log4net from my Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, log4net

I tried to install log4net for use in my Unity project with the following command :

```
Install-Package Unity.log4net
```

However, when I go back to the editor, then back to Visual Studio again, the log4net reference is removed, just like the Unity Editor had regenerated the project or something like that. The log4net reference no longer appears in the reference list and thus the log4net namespace can no longer be found.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one cannot freely add references to a Unity project since Unity has to know about them. DLLs should be placed in a folder of the project called `Plugins` and then it works.

However it's weird that people are telling to use nuget packages. I'm assuming that must work somehow, but I don't know how. The solution above is dirty, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Unity projects require a special process to add NuGet packages. This is because when you open a project in Unity, its Visual Studio project files are regenerated, undoing necessary configurations. To add a package from NuGet to your Unity project you can check this doc from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019